# Learning SQL: Query for rows in diff tables based on if a column value is set

Tags: mysql, database, search

I am doing a side project to help me learn SQL.

I have setup 2 different tables:

```
computers
+------------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
│| Field            | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
│+------------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
│| serial_number    | char(25)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
│| operating_system | char(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
│| purchase_year    | int(4)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
│| assigned_to      | char(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
│+------------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+

employees
│+------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
│| Field      | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
│+------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
│| email      | char(100) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
│| first_name | char(25)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
│| last_name  | char(25)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
│| office     | char(5)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
│| assigned   | char(25)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
│+------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

These both have a few entries while I am testing, but in trying to write a search function based off the employee email, I am reaching a snag with SQL queries. I'm pouring through the documentation, but not understanding it well, and can't find a good example of what I am trying to do to follow along with.

Here is what I am attempting to do with the query:
**I want to grab a the employee row matching email address provided, and if the "employees.assigned" field is set (not null, think EXIST is used?) then I want to also grab the "computers.serial_number" row matching that column value**

I can do what I want with 2 separate queries, but I want to see if it is possible with only one to clean up code and make the query as fast as possible. Any further documentation you think is worthwhile for this project is very welcome as well!

Comment: should probably mention the code language working with mysql is PHP

Comment: It’s a bit unclear how the assigned column links the two tables, but you’re probably looking for outer join, which doesn’t require the other table to have a match and will return nulls for its columns if there isn’t a match.

Comment: the link is employees.assigned will contain the serial number of the computer.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen This is what I am trying for the select query now, but getting a syntax error:
SELECT * FROM employees FULL OUTER JOIN computers ON employees.assigned=computers.serial_number;

Comment: I realize that full outer join is probably the wrong one to use, seems like it returns everything from reading documentation /*EDIT*/ YES, using left or right is giving me some results. Now I need to narrow the scope of the query to only give the fields I want

Comment: Think I have what I need to move forward with this step of the project. I use left join to still get a return value from the query even if the conditional match isn't true, and with PHP, I can easily filter out the NULL values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those people finding this on google:

What I found worked for my need:

```
SELECT * FROM employees LEFT JOIN computers ON employees.assigned=computers.serial_number WHERE email='email@example.com';
```

Comment: would love to know if there is a cleaner or better way of doing this!